# What is the hybridisation of hydrogen in methane?

Tags: bond, hybridization

I am trying to understand hybridisation. In methane carbon has $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridisation, but what is the hybridisation of hydrogen? Is it $\mathrm{sp^3}$? If yes then why?

Comment: What orbitals does hydrogen have available for bonding?

Comment: Orbitals of hydrogen atoms aren't hybridised in $\ce{CH4}$ at all:  1$\mathrm{s}$ orbital of each hydrogen atom forms a $\sigma$-bond with one of the four $\mathrm{sp^3}$-hybridised orbitals of the carbon atom.

Comment: Also, per calculations and experimental data, you could also argue for an unhybridised carbon since there are two different energies of the binding MOs.

Comment: You should answer your own question so that it may be useful to future users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hydrogen does not hybridise, as it only has one **filled** $s$ orbital. Hybridisation is the "mixing of $s$ and $p$ orbitals; [here](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/basicorg/bonding/ethene.html) is a good explanation (for ethane, but it explains the general theory as well).

Answer (score 1):

it is always possible to find the hybridization of the central atom i.e., Carbon. The atomic orbital of hydrogen does not undergo hybridization.